# CSS Keyframe animations on window resize

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to create a css animation and I have hacked together something which works on full screen but not as intended when resizing the window.

I'm using @keyframe animations to move the box and border at slightly different speeds but ultimately coming together at the end of the animation.

Here is a codepen with the markup : https://codepen.io/RichieBrennan/pen/wQrGMJ?editors=1100

```
<header>
   <div class="border"></div>
   <div class="box">
      <h1>This is some text</h1>
   </div>
</header>
```

As I understand, the % is from the center of the element? I'd appreciate someone nudging me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `.border` element is positioned to the `header` element which spans the full `body` not the `.box` element so the % positioning is not matching the `.box` width.

You'll want the `.border` element inside the `.box` element as `CSS` needs the `.box` width.

```
<header>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="border"></div>
        <h1>This is some text</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

Now position the `.border` element 10px (the same as width) to the left (-10px):

```
.border{
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translate(-0%, -50%);
  left: -10px;
  top: 50%;
  animation: move-border 1.1s;
}
```

It's important now to change the `@keyframes move-border` left to a negative % number (adjust this to your own preference).

```
   @keyframes move-border {
      0%{
      left: -29%;
      opacity: 0; 
      }
      100%{
      opacity: 1;
      }
   }
```

Alternatively, You may want to use the `:before` Pseudo instead for cleaner html code:

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>This is some text</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
.box:before
{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translate(-0%, -50%);
  left: -10px;
  top: 50%;
  animation: move-border 1.1s;
}
```

Check out: https://codepen.io/StudioKonKon/pen/xQXgVV

Comment: Thank you! 

It's so obvious to me now. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Great questions.

In general, the `%` is a unit of immediate parent dimensions, and is taken from width/height depending on how you use it. For example, say you have a `1000px x 500px` container. If your child has `left: 50%` or `right: 50%`, you'll be positioning the child with a `500px` (half of 1000) measurement, anchored from left or right. The same rules apply to `top: 50%` or `bottom: 50%`, except you'll now be dealing with `250px` (half of 500). To be honest, I never memorized or stepped myself through anything (hence the poor explanation), I've just relied on browser developer tools for hacking and this knowledge follows along.

What you can do to solve your positioning issue is placing `position: relative` on a parent element -- your header. You did this, but I'm going to re-explain just to be thorough.

`position: absolute` normally allows an element to be positioned (top, left, right, or bottom) with respect to the browser window; `top: 0px; left: 0px;` would be the top left corner. Placing `position: relative` or `absolute` on a parent allows all `position: absolute` child elements to be relative with respect to their parent.

In the following example, `.some-child` will be `20px` away from anything because all dimensions are relative to the parent.

```
.some-parent {
     margin: 20px;
     position: relative;
}

.some-child {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
}
```

Using this knowledge, your header should be relative, and your border and box can both be absolute. However, you have to make sure your `header` is constrained to the correct dimensions, and you should be using absolute pixels to determine offsets. This explanation has gotten a bit out of hand, so I'll just show you what I mean.

```css
* {
  /* helpful for debugging, but use your developer tools */
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

header{
  height: 200px;
  width: 410px;
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
}

.border{
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  /* see comment below
  transform: translate(-0%, -50%);*/
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%; /* height matches parent */
  animation: move-border 1.1s;
}

.box{
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  /* don't need this! You should try to make
     your animations animate to transform: none,
     which are essentially transform: translate(0, 0).
     Makes it a lot easier to layout things
     and the move-box animation automatically transforms
     back to the original state (if no 100% is defined)
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  background-color: white;
  animation: move-box 0.8s;
}

.box h1{
  /* doesn't need to be absolute! but you can play with these numbers,
     they will be relative to .box
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  top: 50px;
  */
  animation: fadein 2s ease-in;
}

@keyframes move-box {
  0% {
   
  left: 35%;
  opacity: 0; 
  }
  100%{
  }
}

@keyframes move-border {
  0%{
  left: 22%;
  opacity: 0; 
  }
  100%{
  opacity: 1;
  }
  
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100%{opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>This is some text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="border"></div>
</header>
```

To center your header like before, just wrap it in another container and perform some centering logic in there.

There's a lot going on there and I'm certain you're on the verge of being bored to death, but feel free to leave any questions in the comments. I'll do my best to answer them. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy explanation Sheng. It's given me a better understanding of the issue. The other commenter also pointed out that the border was takings its positioning from the header. I appreaciate you taking the time to explain that. Thanks!

Comment: @Bob Happy to help! Welcome to SO.